# Get lat and lng from a place with google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have an issue with taking the values of lat and lng from a place with google maps javascript api places searchbox.

This is the code which google provides from being able to search for places inside the searchbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location

      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // [END region_getplaces]
}

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And now i want to get the exact values of lat and lng to some variables in javascript.
After some research i have found this

```
var location = place.geometry.location;
var lat = location.lat();
var lng = location.lng();
```

So when i `console.log` the variables `lat` and `lng` to be appearead at the console of chrome. The problem is that i cant quite understand where should i integrate the lat and lng code from location so it can work with the example from google?

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to do with the latitude and longitude?

Comment: @geocodezip i would like to put them in 2 different variables (lat and lng) and print them out with console.log. Like i say in the last paragraph

Comment: You are putting them in separate values.  What good does printing them to the console log do?  Currently the `console.log` is running before the autocomplete values are returned (I get a javascript error `Uncaught TypeError: location.lat is not a function`, it is outside the callback function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}

#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}

.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}

#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}

#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

    </style>
    <title>Places Searchbox</title>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
  // This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
  // feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
  // pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

  function initAutocomplete() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
   center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
   zoom: 13,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
   searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];
    // [START region_getplaces]
    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
   var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

   if (places.length == 0) {
     return;
   }

   // Clear out the old markers.
   markers.forEach(function(marker) {
     marker.setMap(null);
   });
   markers = [];

   // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
   places.forEach(function(place) {
     var icon = {
    url: place.icon,
    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
     };
     console.log("latitude: " + place.geometry.location.lat() + ", longitude: " + place.geometry.location.lng());

     // Create a marker for each place.
     markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: icon,
    title: place.name,
    position: place.geometry.location

     }));

     if (place.geometry.viewport) {
    // Only geocodes have viewport.
    bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
     } else {
    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
     }
   });
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
    // [END region_getplaces]
  }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API-KEY]&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You awsome!